# If we use parameterized url as canonical url, will it be a problem in terms of seo?

Tags: seo

I am a Blogger user, Blogger redirects from the standard url and adds the ?m=1 parameter to the end of the url for logins from mobile devices.

This redirect causes page speed delays.

I'm using a responsive theme, so if I change the standard urls with the ?m=1 parameter, will it be a problem for seo?

Example URL;

/2021/02/post-page.html?m=1

Comment: See the answer to this question: [Should query strings be included or removed from the canonical tag?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/114622/should-query-strings-be-included-or-removed-from-the-canonical-tag)

Comment: i will add parameter to all urls.is this a problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per your example, as long as `https://example.com/2021/02/post-page.html` does *not* exist, it will not be a problem if `https://example.com/2021/02/post-page.html?m=1` is declared canonical.

For more information about query strings and canonicals see the answer to the question: [Should query strings be included or removed from the canonical tag?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/114622/should-query-strings-be-included-or-removed-from-the-canonical-tag)

Comment: Thank you for your answer